# Independent left and right columns

Tags: formatting, columns

I'm trying to write something with two columns that spans multiple pages.

I want to put one thing in the left side and one in the right side. Is there ``proper'' way of doing this, or should I just try and bodge it with tabular/table?

Comment: Should the columns be independent so that they contain separate texts or does `twocolumn`, e.g. `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`, work for you?

Comment: yeah, independent in the not-twocolumn sense.

Comment: Then your question seems to be technically similar too http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30410/another-body-text-in-the-margin

Comment: Perhaps the [`changepage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) is what you're after? It provides the `adjustwidth` environment.

Comment: Thanks guys. Still, both of these seem to be treating the two columns like a margin + text (unless I'm wrong about this).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at [CTAN by Topic](https://ctan.org/topic/parallel) I've found reference to

> - [parallel](https://ctan.org/pkg/parallel): Provides a parallel environment which allows two potentially different texts to be typeset in two columns, while
>     maintaining alignment. The two columns may be on the same page, or on
>     facing pages.
> - [parcolumns](https://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns): Provides an environment for typesetting text in two or more parallel columns (as for example, in a multiply translated text)
> - [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol): The package provides yet another multi-column typesetting mechanism by which you produce multi-column (e.g., bilingual) document
>     switching and synchronizing each corresponding part in “parallel”.
> - [parrun](https://ctan.org/pkg/parrun): For typesetting translated text and the original source, parallel on the same page, one above the other.

I've never used them but I hope some of them will suit your needs.

Comment: paracol looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: would vote it up if I had any rep ;)

Comment: 2nd link is DEAD! Wait, actually, all links are dead.

Comment: @Rainb It seems to work now.