# Dividing the page equally with geometry package

Tags: two-column, minipage

I'm wondering about dividing the page in 2 independent parts. I did it with minipage :
first was `\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} .. \end{minipage}` and second was
`\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} ... \end{minipage}` .
This works but is there some way to equally divide it without specifying width ?
I'm intending to use `\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}` and would like that TeX divide it on equal parts.

edit: I have another problem. Putting box around column is breaking 2 columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  \kant[1-2]
  \kant[1-2]
  \kant[1-2]
  \switchcolumn
  \kant[3-4]
  \end{paracol}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to set up two equally wide columns of text. How is LaTeX supposed to know how wide you want the columns to be? Separately, have you looked into setting the option `twocolumn` when executing the `\documentclass` instruction?

Comment: twocolumn doesn't set independent columns

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32154/independent-left-and-right-columns

Comment: Please be specific about what you mean by "independent columns."

Comment: When writing on the end of first column, doesn't continue in second column but on 1 column on second page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it.

A sample with `paracol`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  \kant[1-2]
  \switchcolumn
  \kant[3-4]
  \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `parcolumns`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
        \begin{parcolumns}{2}            
            \colchunk{ %
                \kant[1-2]
            }
            \colchunk{ %
                \kant[3-4]
            }
            \colplacechunks
        \end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Output same as above.

With `parallel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Parallel}[v]{0.49\textwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
    \ParallelLText{\kant[1-2]} 
    \ParallelRText{\kant[3-4]} 
    \ParallelPar
  \end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the brute force:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
    \kant[1-2] &  \kant[3-4]
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Figure same as first one.

Comment: Thx, with Parallel why did you put 0.49 width?

Comment: @vejn Just to accommodate the vertical line.

Comment: Which method is best to use for math article, equations and images?

Comment: @vejn `paracol` is neater. `parcolumns` and parallel may also be used.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited first post. Another problem occured.

Comment: @vejn Instead of editing the question, you should ask a new one with all the details. You didn't specify that you need a box. You may use `tabularx` solution then.